# Can't telnet from windows machine to OS X laptop on same network?

Tags: windows, mac-osx, telnet, networking

I'm trying to telnet from my windows box into a service running on a known-available port on a mac laptop, but the connection is getting refused.

- I can telnet into the service locally.
- Firewalls are set to pass-through on both ends.
- Wiresharking the line shows that the SYN gets responded to with a RST, ACK. No connection is established.

What might be going on here? (Thanks in advance!)

Comment: Just a note: it looks like the service may be bound to 'localhost' instead of to my IP or the loopback. I'll try these and update once I have results.

Comment: `localhost` is the loopback, and that will prevent connection from outside the device.  Try 0.0.0.0.

Comment: Don't use telnet, use ssh.

Comment: @Paul, I didn't realize I could specify the port to be used with ssh. (Also, the service at the other end isn't SSH.) Can you clarify a bit what you're suggesting?

Comment: @Shane, this seems to be the problem. Thank you so much. Maybe you could expand your comment into an answer?

Comment: @Paul Tomblin: Debugging/testing a text based protocol (like SMTP, HTTP, IMAP) is a perfectly valid use case for telnet (the program). SSH is not a replacement in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`localhost` is the hostname for the loopback address - that will be the resolved hostname for both 127.0.0.1 and ::1.  If a service is bound to one of these addresses, it will only be available to attempts to connect locally to the loopback address.

A service that needs to listen for connections over the network should listen on a non-loopback address; you can manually specify the addresses to listen on, or go with the "easy route" of binding to 0.0.0.0 (for IPv6, ::) to listen on all addresses (including the loopback).

Comment: You can use `netstat -an | grep LISTEN` to see what ports and addresses your TCP listeners are bound to.